# Bash: Moving Files with Regex that Matches Pattern of Script Arugment and Fixed Text

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a backup script that takes a directory and directory/file name as arguments to the script. The problem is curating the target directory of the backups. For safety, I'm currently moving the files into MacOS `~/.Trash/`. The problem is that I want to support having spaces in the target directory's file name, but escaping the path in `mv` prevents shell expansion of `*`.

The script in question:

```
# Usage: backup-to-dropbox.sh "path/containing/target" "target dir"
cd "$1"
DATE=`date "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"`
SOURCE="$2"
mv "~/Dropbox/Backups/$SOURCE*.tgz" ~/.Trash/ ## Problem line here
tar -czf "$SOURCE $DATE.tgz" "$SOURCE/"
mv "$SOURCE $DATE.tgz" ~/Dropbox/Backups/
```

How can I match all the files with this known, arbitrary prefix and fixed extension?

Comment: I tried it and had no issues.  Can you run the script with `set -x` to see what happens at that line.  I'll suspect that you have too many files and may exceed the command line buffer of 1024 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words can be partially quoted. Be sure not to quote anything expanded by the shell.

```
mv ~/"Dropbox/Backups/$SOURCE"*.tgz ~/.Trash/
```

Comment: Tried using this line. Error: `mv: rename ~/Dropbox/Backups/Test Dir*.tgz to /Users/user-redacted/.Trash/Test Dir*.tgz: No such file or directory`. Same for a directory with no spaces in its name.

Comment: Aha! Works with `mv ~/"Dropbox/Backups/$SOURCE"*.tgz ~/.Trash/`

Comment: Good catch.  That's what I get for answering from an iPad. ;^)